# Understanding how List head works

Tags: core-language, language-design

I am trying to understand how Wolfram Language is actually meant to work and here is something that I fail to understand.

*Apply[f, expr] replaces the head of expr by f.*

So how come I get different results as shown below in Out[5] and Out[6]. I would expect Out[5] to produce a list exactly as Out[6] does.

```
In[5]:= List[a + b + c]

Out[5]= {a + b + c}

In[8]:= Trace[List[a + b + c]]

Out[8]= {}

In[6]:= Apply[List, a + b + c]

Out[6]= {a, b, c}

In[7]:= Trace[Apply[List, a + b + c]]

Out[7]= {List@@(a+b+c),{a,b,c}}
```

References:
https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5216/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In (5) you have the following expression:

```
List[a + b + c] // FullForm
```

> `List[Plus[a,b,c]]`

In (6) you have this expression:

```
Apply[List,Plus[a,b,c]]]
```

It seems like you are expecting `Apply` to wrap `List` around `Plus[a,b,c]` to form `List[Plus[a,b,c]]`. But that's not what the documentation says. The documentation says that `Apply` "replaces the head of expr by f". In this case, the head is `Plus` and `f` is `List`. Consequently, the output is `List[a, b, c]`.

Comment: I think *FullForm* provides the best transparency to understand what is the underlying Expression. Thanks a lot for providing an answer with demonstration.